# How to do reverse prediction in python (keras)?

Tags: python, neural-network, theano, prediction, keras

I have a classification neural network which I trained in a very large dataset with a fair amount of accuracy and prediction. Now I want to reverse prediction (normal prediction: **input->output** reverse prediction **input<-output**).

This is an example neural network made for this question. Here I take natural numbers and try to classify it as odd or even numbers using a neural network.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy as np

#model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1,input_dim=1))
model.add(Dense(4))
model.add(Dense(4))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary

#creating natural number features and binary odd and even targets
n=500
#natural numbers
x=np.arange(1,n)
x=x.reshape(n-1,1)
#even
y1=np.where(x%2==0,1,0)
#odd
y2=np.where(x%2!=0,1,0)

#target
Y=np.column_stack([y1,y2])

#model training
model.fit(x,Y,validation_split=0.3)

y_dash=np.arange(n,n+10)

#model prediction
model.predict(y_dash)
```

its accuracy is 50% (which is more than enough for this sample ANN)

```
349/349 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.7077 - acc: 0.4871 - val_loss: 0.6991 - val_acc: 0.5000
```

How can I reverse prediction of this neural network?

For example If I want this neural network to output some odd numbers.